# Assigning event handler

Tags: javascript, html

Assigning event handler like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction);
```

is it required for the handler function to be defined before the assignment code? In other words if the codes below

```
function myFunction() {...}
...
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction);
```

and

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction);
...
function myFunction() {...}
```

are identical?

Comment: well.. did you try it for yourself...? What did you find...?

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti: Trying it can be useful, but only tells you whether it works on the JavaScript engine(s) where you tried it, as opposed to whether it's *supposed* to work.

Comment: `function declaration` is hoisted which means it is evaluated before any other code in current context..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...are identical?

They are **if** you use the form you've shown, which is a function *declaration*. Function declarations are processed before any step-by-step code in the scope. If you used a function *expression* instead (`var myFunction = function() { ... };`), it would have to be *before* the `addEventListener` call. More about the difference in [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) answers.